# Object stored in Stack has field "erased"

Tags: c#, stack

I have a `Stack<Query>` where `Query` is the following:

```
public class Query
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _distinguishedNames;
    private readonly string _searchText;

    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    public Query(
        QueryType queryType,
        Scope scope = null,
        IEnumerable<string> distinguishedNames = null,
        string searchText = null)
    {
        QueryType = queryType;
        Scope = scope;
        _distinguishedNames = distinguishedNames;
        _searchText = searchText;
    }

    private CancellationToken CancellationToken
        => _cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    public Scope Scope { get; }

    public IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> Data { get; private set; }

    public QueryType QueryType { get; }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    }

    public void DisposeData()
    {
        Data = null;
    }

    public async Task Execute()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Data = new Searcher(
                QueryType,
                Scope,
                _distinguishedNames,
                CancellationToken,
                _searchText).GetData();
        },
        _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        await task;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return QueryType.ToString();
    }
}
```

The class managing the queries contains the following relevant portions:

```
Stack<Query> Queries = new Stack<Query>();

private async void ExecuteRunPreviousQuery()
{
    Queries.Pop();
    await RunQuery(Queries.Pop());
}

private async Task RunQuery(
    QueryType queryType,
    Scope scope = null,
    IEnumerable<string> selectedItemDistinguishedNames = null,
    string searchText = null)
{
    await RunQuery(
        new Query(
            queryType,
            scope,
            selectedItemDistinguishedNames,
            searchText));
}

private async Task RunQuery(Query query)
{
    StartTask();
    try
    {
        Queries.Push(query);
        await Queries.Peek().Execute();
        Data = Queries.Peek().Data.ToDataTable().AsDataView();
        ContextMenuItems = GenerateContextMenuItems();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e)
    {
        ShowMessage(e.Message);
        ResetQuery();
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        ShowMessage("Operation was cancelled.");
        ResetQuery();
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException)
    {
        ShowMessage(
            "No results of desired type found in selected context.");
        ResetQuery();
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException)
    {
        ShowMessage("The selected query is too large to run.");
        ResetQuery();
    }

    FinishTask();
}
```

I can run any query just fine, but if I try to run the previous query method, the query always has its `_distinguishedNames` field set to empty, even if the field previously had content. Not null, just somehow empty. The `Searcher` class to which `_distinguishedNames` is passed does not manipulate it; searcher simply iterates over it. I even tried passing a copy of `_distinguishedNames` just to ensure that searcher was not somehow messing with it, and that did not change anything.

To clarify, I call `RunQuery` with parameters of `QueryType` and a non-empty `IEnumerable<string>`. It executes without problem. I then call `RunQuery` again with some other parameters, and it executes again without problem. I then call `ExecuteRunPreviousQuery` and the first query fails to run properly because the `IEnumerable<string>` that is supposed to be stored in `_distinguishedNames` is now empty.

If you want to see any other code, please let me know. To the best of my knowledge, this is a MCVE.

Comment: Remove defaults to null in the constructor. You should probably even protect your constructor with `if (a == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));` calls for each of your argument. It is very unlikely that the stack is destroying your reference, as a stack is built as a generic which have no knowledge of its element type.

Comment: @sturcotte Well, sometimes the arguments can be null. My problem is not with null elements. It is with an object where I know a field is not null (or empty), the field somehow becomes empty when I pop it from a stack.

Comment: Like I've said, this is very unlikely. I can guarantee you the bug in in the argument you pass to your query. A stack is generic, and thus does not have any knowledge of its element. It cannot possibly act on it. Your fields are not weak references; therefore the garbage collection cannot reclaim their memory. The only possibility left is a bug on your side, most likely in your constructor. You Either construct a query with less than 4 arguments, or your arguments were null all along.

Comment: @sturcotte06 And as I have said, the issue is that the field (of type `readonly IEnumerable<string>`) is known at one point to contain elements, and then, when the object containing that field is popped from the stack, it is empty (but not null). If that still isn't clear, I create a query object with a `distinguishedNames` non-empty `IEnumerable<string>` parameter, the `_distinguishedNames` field is then set to that parameter. The query then does what it needs to with the parameter. I push the query to a stack, pop it, and then the field's IEnumerable is empty, and the query no longer works.

Comment: It's an IEnumerable. Depending on its implementation, it might not be possible to view its data twice (Read might be destructive). I'm 100% certain it's either a bug in your application or a misunderstanding of yours regarding enumerable types. It has nothing to do with the stack, unless the stack is a custom implementation. Imagine an IEnumerable implementation over a socket. Each element is a line of text from the socket. You would not be able to reset the IEnumerable as data read from a socket can only be read once. Therefore, if you observe the data once, there is no going back.

Comment: @sturcotte06 Thanks, switching from IEnumerable to IList fixed it, even though ToList didn't change anything earlier when I tried that.